# Photoshop Copy one Text Layer and change font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I want to make a logo. I want to make a text layer and copy it for example 100 times and change each font. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Apart from sounding like a horrible idea it's possible, if I understand it correctly. Please check [ask] to learn what kind of questions you could ask here, then [edit] your question to add more info. Also check https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you have 100 possible fonts for a logo.. you may want to narrow the idea down a bit more.

Comment: You can make the logo and leave the text area blank. Then create different layers, paste in the text, and convert the font on each layer differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try photoshop actions. You can set any F keys or combinations to do at least the copy paste part. What I am doubtful about is that if it can open the font menu for you or not. Because it doesn’t store key strokes rather the final memory state.